# flutter_mapbox_navigation AAPT:error:resource string/mapbox_access_token (aka eopeter.flutter_mapbox_navigation:string/mapbox_access_token) not found

Tags: android, flutter, apk, mapbox, mapbox-navigation

I'm using flutter_mapbox_navigation to navigate in my flutter app. I add it and set all configuration things. I add it in debug mode with android studio and the app works fine in android and in iOS.

But if instead of run it, I try to build apk I get this error:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':flutter_mapbox_navigation:verifyReleaseResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.VerifyLibraryResourcesTask$Action
> Android resource linking failed
> ERROR:/Users/nicolasvermi/Documents/development/myzona-flutter/build/flutter_mapbox_navigation/intermediates/merged_res/release/layout/navigation_activity.xml:2: AAPT: error: resource string/mapbox_access_token (aka eopeter.flutter_mapbox_navigation:string/mapbox_access_token) not found.

My flutter doctor here:

Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):

- [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.11, on macOS 13.1 22C65
  darwin-arm64, locale en-GB)
- [✓] Android toolchain - develop for
  Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
- [✓] Xcode - develop for
  iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3)
- [✓] Chrome - develop for the web
- [✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
- [✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
- [✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2022.3.2)
- [✓] Connected device (2 available) [✓] HTTP Host Availability

android build.gradle code:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven'
            authentication {
                basic(BasicAuthentication)
            }
            credentials {
                username = "mapbox"
                password = project.properties['MY SecretKey'] ?: ""
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven'
            authentication {
                basic(BasicAuthentication)
            }
            credentials {
                username = "mapbox"
                password = project.properties['MY SecretKey'] ?: ""
            }
        }
        configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy {
                force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1"
            }
        }
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: can you please add the code which you've used in `android/build.gradle` ?

Comment: yes, I add it in the post

Comment: you added your secret key in `android/gradle.properties` ?

Comment: yes, in this way

org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN=sk.*******

Comment: Yeah si technically your variable name `MAPBOX_DOWNLOAD_TOKEN` should be replaced by `MY SecretKey` which you declared in `android/build.gradle`

Comment: yes I know 'My SecretKey' is a placeholder to obscure my secret key

Answer (score 0):

You can add a release resource by clicking the "res" folder under your android app and do "New Resource" if using Android Studio and specify if you would like to add a main, debug, release resource as shown in the screenshot below:

[image: Add config Specific Resource]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But I think the problem is not to add a resource but to find it. It not works for my case your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I fix it by following some instruction in this link https://github.com/eopeter/flutter_mapbox_navigation/issues/211